# Cannot read request body in Owin (stuck in ReadAsStringAsync)

Tags: c#, azure, owin

Running OWIN self-hosting web service in Azure Service Fabric behind Azure Load Balancer and Azure Traffic Manager Profile with multiple instances.
About 2% of web requests stuck when service is trying to read the request body from incoming requests to string using **HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync**. So the **ReadAsStringAsync** fails after timeout :

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.

Web service receives request with different sizes most of them are small but some could be up to 60K. The number of concurrent pending requests/instance is about 900 and CPU load ~30%.
Scaling out number of services helps a little bit but does not solve it completely, I am also trying to understand what is the root cause.
Here is the setting I override in OwinHttpListener:

```
listener.SetRequestProcessingLimits(Environment.ProcessorCount * 5, int.MaxValue);
listener.SetRequestQueueLimit(10000);
```

Any ideas of the root cause and/or how to fix it?
Owin ver:

> PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" Version="5.2.6"

Comment: Did you find a cure for this? Experiencing similar difficulties right now.